# Constantly Restarting of SQL Instances in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I have 4 instances of SQL in GCP, all of this are restarting constantly.

[This is the log from one of this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zc6l.png)

From today this problem is happening, and they go 5 times on this day, I can not find more information. Please, any ideas of what I have to do?

The Properties of this Instance:

```
Generation                  1st Generation
Database version            MySQL 5.5
Backup window               1:00 AM — 5:00 AM (UTC-5)
Binary log                  Disabled
File system replication     Asynchronous
Preferred location          Follow app "xxxxxxxxx"
Tier                        D16
Pricing plan                Package
Activation Policy           Always
Labels                      d16
Storage usage               18GB
Read/write operations avg   6/s
Mysql queries avg           40/s
Read/write InnoDB pages avg 5/s
InnoDB data fsync           4/s
InnoDB log fsync            4/s
Active connections          20/s
```

I suspect of Backup Operations, but how stop that? In Operations Logs appears this
Jun 27, 2019, 3:02:46 AM    Backup   An unknown error occurred
Jun 26, 2019, 4:16:15 AM    Backup   An unknown error occurred
Jun 26, 2019, 3:16:14 AM    Backup   An unknown error occurred

Thanks in advance

Issue published in https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136738275

Comment: Are you using any startup flags for your Google Cloud SQL instances? [Why you did not upgrade to 2gen instances?](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/upgrade-2nd-gen). Did you try to perform manual backup?

Comment: Google Cloud Support here! To investigate the issue, there are more information needed, that are private and can not be posted here. 
If you have a Google Cloud support, please fill a support ticket.
If you do not have support, please open [a private Google issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164) using your project ID. 
Than post the link to issue that you created as a comment here. 
With this link I can take a look into your project.

Comment: I can't upgrade yet to 2gen, because the project is in production 24/7, for years, and still served with App Engine Standard with python 2.7 and Django1.5, very old, which are not compatible with 2gen SQL, I going to develop a new version of the project with the news libraries but this take me a lot of time. While I need to continue supporting this version.
I create a new Issue, the link is:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136738275
Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi, thank you, your issue is already being worked on. Any updates are going to be posted on the internal issue thread.